# Get the index of mysql result raw

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:-

```
id | name
 1 | abc
 5 | def
 9 | ghi
 10 | jkl
 11 | mno
 12 | pqr
```

I want to get the index of a given id

example:-

```
SELECT `id`, INDEX FROM `table` WHERE `id`>5
// INDEX is the function that I want
```

result:-

```
id | INDEX
 9 | 3
 10 | 4
 11 | 5
 12 | 6
```

I googled it and not found a answer.

Thanks in advance for nay help.

Comment: Is id column set an auto increment ?

Comment: Rows in a relational database represent unordered sets. There is no 'index', except for that inferred from an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes. but some starting `id`s deleted

Comment: Also for id=9 index should be 3 not 2 right ?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid no problem if zero based or one based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get this by

```
select max(id) id,count(*)
from demo
where id < 9;
```

If id column is set to auto increment

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7be7a/4)

For multiple rows you can do a self left join

```
select a.id,count(*)
from demo a
left join demo b on a.id >= b.id
group by a.id
having a.id > 5
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7be7a/15)

Comment: If i want more than one raws? Do i want to use it as a sub query? Or other solution do you have?

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi more than one rows means what exactly ,can you update your question

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi i have updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

SELECT `id`, (select count(1) from `table` where id<9) FROM `table` WHERE `id`=9;

Comment: hope this help full

Comment: @janith1024 Yes it is an answer. But I like to a answer without sub queries.